# Ошибка вывода текста.

Tags: c#

Скажите почему такая ошибка происходит? Есть код

```
    private void открытьToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Title = "Открыть";
        dlg.Filter = "txt|*.txt";
        dlg.ShowDialog();
        richTextBox1.LoadFile(dlg.FileName , RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText );
    }
```

А у меня вместо текста (в richtextbox'e) , у меня абра-кодабра какая-то... что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте кодировку исходного файла, возможно это Unicode, если это так, то исправить вызов на

```
richTextBox1.LoadFile(dlg.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText);
```

либо изменить кодировку исходного файла. Можно еще так

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dlg.FileName, Encoding.Default);
richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

Comment: Я просто хочу сделать блокнот, для сохранения файла в формате .txt, и с возможностью сохранения и открытия файла...

Comment: М.б есть другие способы открытия файла и передачи его внутренностей в richtextbox?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал по быстрому пример, используя ваш код обработчика - работает исправно (проверил на нескольких файлах с разной кодировкой). Но использовать имена контролов и соответственно обработчиков на русском языке (даже смешанном) - это ужас!!!

Я имею ввиду это:

> открытьToolStripButton_Click

- или это очепятка? :)